# Unknown error while debugging a QT-application with Visual Studio Code and CMake-Tools

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, cmake

I try to debug a QT-Application in Visual Studio Code with CMake Tools. Everything works fine, but when I try to open a fileOpenDialog, the debugging crashes with an error:

Unable to open 'memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-4WA41p/glibc-2.30/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-4WA41p/glibc-2.30/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S').

Does anybody have an idea? When starting the application from system directly it works fine.

Thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, it's because while debugging, `gdb` tries to collect all the callstack but for some reasons like for instance you're not running VS Code under root (and obviously you don't have to, but some libs are in root directories and may not be accessed by user application) or because there are required libs for running in the system, but they are just compiled binaries without source code, VS Code cannot show you the content of these files. These are not mistakes of a debug process or wrong work of your code, they are simply VS Code's errors and never mind them.

Comment: Thank you, Yevhenii Mamontov, I thougth so too. And since VSC istn't supposed to run as root, I guess there sadly isn't a solution for VSC :/

Answer (score 0):

If your desktop-environment is Gnome, you can add below in environment of `launch.json`.

```
"environment": [{"name":"SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN","value":"gen"}]
```